# UIButton in UITableView, selector applied on several buttons

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, selector

I'm currently working in a `UITableView`, each cell containing a button with a specific `UIImage` in background. I'd like to change this image when the button is clicked in a cell.

I have this code, working perfectly but when I click on a button, several buttons are modified - every 5 buttons, don't know why. Here's the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [myCell.favorite addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed_fav:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return myCell;
}

- (void)pressed_fav:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *myButton = sender;

    [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

`myCell` is an instance of a customized cell, containing an `IBOutlet` 'favorite' pointing to the `UIButton`.

Comment: Cany you post the complete code for your tableView:ellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Answer (score 1):

Its because `UITableView` re-uses cell.
You must have some logic in cellForRowAtIndexPath method to identify the image of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guy !

Actually, when I delete the line:

```
myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cinemaCell"];
```

It does not display the cell (it's well allocated and initialised instead).

Comment: It's okay, I just forgot to init the brand new cell each time, sorry guy!